# How to sort an array based from another array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How to sort an array based on another array in php? I have this list of persons, actually they are 1300 + people... I will only display 22 people here :)

**persons array:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [name] => Kay [site] => ex [rate] => 10 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [name] => Kat [site] => ih [rate] => 9.7 )
    [2] => Array ( [name] => Kate [site] => tp [rate] => 9 )
    [3] => Array ( [name] => rina [site] => tc [rate] => 9.8 )
    [4] => Array ( [name] => Katay [site] => cfnm [rate] => 6.8 )
    [5] => Array ( [name] => teriay [site] => sn [rate] => 7.6 )
    [6] => Array ( [name] => Kaay [site] => tla [rate] => 9.7 )
    [7] => Array ( [name] => na Kay [site] => bsc [rate] => 9.5 )
    [8] => Array ( [name] => qwerty [site] => tdp [rate] => 9.5 )
    [9] => Array ( [name] => Katey [site] => hd [rate] => 9.4 )
    [10] => Array ( [name] => Kat Kay [site] => ss [rate] => 9.2 )
    [11] => Array ( [name] => ina Kay [site] => pv [rate] => 9.43 )
    [12] => Array ( [name] => ina [site] => rat [rate] => 9.32 )
    [13] => Array ( [name] => atay [site] => trw [rate] => 9.32 )
    [14] => Array ( [name] => erina [site] => tlm [rate] => 9.43 )
    [15] => Array ( [name] => Ky [site] => ol [rate] => 8.34 )
    [16] => Array ( [name] => ikay [site] => tb [rate] => 7.34 )
    [17] => Array ( [name] => jay [site] => ta [rate] => 6.5 )
    [18] => Array ( [name] => saday [site] => hfy [rate] => 4.6 )
    [19] => Array ( [name] => tarans [site] => sd [rate] => 6.54 )
    [20] => Array ( [name] => dastw [site] => si [rate] => 6.4 )
    [21] => Array ( [name] => dyr say [site] => ex [rate] => 7.6 )
)
```

and there is an another array called site which i want to display them accordingly, only one person per site per loop and when the site array reached to the end then it will start to top until the lists of persons are done reading.

by **site order array**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [acronym] => exs [site_order] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [acronym] => ts [site_order] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [acronym] => ih [site_order] => 2 ) 
[3] => Array ( [acronym] => tp [site_order] => 3 ) 
[4] => Array ( [acronym] => tc [site_order] => 4 ) 
[5] => Array ( [acronym] => cfnm [site_order] => 5 ) 
[6] => Array ( [acronym] => sn [site_order] => 6 ) 
[7] => Array ( [acronym] => tla [site_order] => 7 ) 
[8] => Array ( [acronym] => bsc [site_order] => 8 ) 
[9] => Array ( [acronym] => tdp [site_order] => 9 ) 
[10] => Array ( [acronym] => lhd [site_order] => 10 ) 
[11] => Array ( [acronym] => ss [site_order] => 11 ) 
[12] => Array ( [acronym] => pov [site_order] => 12 ) 
[13] => Array ( [acronym] => rat [site_order] => 13 ) 
[14] => Array ( [acronym] => trw [site_order] => 14 ) 
[15] => Array ( [acronym] => tgs [site_order] => 15 ) 
[16] => Array ( [acronym] => tlm [site_order] => 16 ) 
[17] => Array ( [acronym] => ol [site_order] => 17 ) 
[18] => Array ( [acronym] => tb [site_order] => 18 ) 
[19] => Array ( [acronym] => ta [site_order] => 19 ) 
[20] => Array ( [acronym] => hfy [site_order] => 20 ) 
[21] => Array ( [acronym] => sd [site_order] => 21 ) 
[22] => Array ( [acronym] => si [site_order] => 22 ) 
[23] => Array ( [acronym] => tse [site_order] => 23 ) 
[24] => Array ( [acronym] => ih [site_order] => 24 ) 
)
```

I also want to display them by rate. but I cant even display a correct data because when the site array foreach is finish then it stop loading on people. this is what my code so far...

```
$x = 0;
$num = 0;
foreach ($site as $item) {
        foreach ($data as $person)
        {
            if($site[$num]['acronym'] == $persons['site'] && $x != 1)
            {
                echo 'name: '.$person['site'].'<br>';
                echo 'site: '.$person['name'].'<br>';
                echo '<br>';

                $x++;
            }
        }
        $x = 0;
    $num++;
}
```

what output i want is for example:

```
site: ex
name: kay
rate: 10

site: tp
name: kate
rate: 9

site: tc
name: rina
rate: 9.8

site: ih
name: kat
rate: 9.7

site: tla
name: Kaay
rate: 9.7
.
.
.
and so on
```

note that I want a condition that:
loop persons order by site orders and order by rate but only one person per site loop.

I know it sounds bit complicated but please help me. i searched so much thread here that has the same problem as me, but no luck. :'(

Comment: can you add your desired output?

Comment: yes sure @roullie wait a minute

Comment: @roullie do you have any idea how? pls help me. hehe i already edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is a possible solution:

```
$already_printed = Array();
$total_of_people = count($people);
// while there is someone that was not printed yet
while(count($already_printed) < $total_of_people){
  // iterate thought each site
  foreach($sites as $site){
      // take each person and its position in the array
      foreach ($people as $i => $person){
          // if this i-th person was not printed yet
          // and is related to this $site
          if (! isset($already_printed[$i])
              && $person['site'] == $site['acronym']){
                // print this person
                echo 'site: '.$person['site'].'<br>';
                echo 'name: '.$person['name'].'<br>';
                echo '<br>';
                // mark this i-th person as printed
                $already_printed[$i] = true;
          }

      }
  }
}
```

The array `already_printed` is used to know who was already printed to avoid double printing. When its size is equal to the total of people, then, we printed everybody, so, we can stop (this is what the outer loop does).

Comment: yeah i think so, gonna try this. but i think this code `foreach($sites as $site)` must be `foreach($site as $sites)` right?

Comment: Hey bud @vitor can you explain me how this works? `$person = $people[$i];` is this directly called on the `persons=array()` above?

Comment: im having an error here it says `Undefined offset: 1` on the `$data = $data[$i];`

Comment: About the foreach: $sites is the array with all the sites and $site is the variable containing a single site. I think the syntax is right.

Comment: I am using `$people` as the name of the first array you wrote in your question and `$ites` as the name of the second one. And I am using no variable called `$data`, so, this error couldn't happen.

Comment: I edited the answer writing more comments in the code and I changed the third loop.

Comment: I saw the edition you suggested and was rejected... I just used different variables names. It's very simple to take this code and adapt to you. Is there anything wrong yet? If there is, please, tell me what's missing. If this answer is already right, please, accept it as the right one.

Comment: I tried the one you made last time but there is missing there, that is the girls per site. they are printing all persons per site. as I said above it must be one person per site. the edition i put on your answer is an additional that made the code works. but the only thing is also not in there is in rate order.

Comment: but so far this answer is close on what I looking for then i will accept it as an answer! :) (y)

Comment: I understood your point about "one person per site". I think you just have to put a break inside the if, after printing the information. Because doing it, you go to the next site after printing one person, as you want.

Comment: Ans, in order to display the people by rate, you just have to sort the array people by the attribute rate before the line `while(count($already_printed) < $total_of_people)`. Doing so, the first person found for each site will be the top rated person, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to organize that large array into a format that doesn't force you to iterate through it more times than necessary.  Give this a shot:

```
$highest = array();

foreach ($data as $person) {
    if (!array_key_exists($person['site'], $highest) || ($person['rate'] > $highest[$person['site']]['rate'])) {
        $highest[$person['site']] = $person;
    }
}

foreach ($site as $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item['acronym'], $highest)) {
        echo "site: {$highest[$item['acronym']]['site']}<br />name:{$highest[$item['acronym']]['name']}<br />rate:{$highest[$item['acronym']]['rate']}";
    }
}
```

As a side note, good call on changing 'girls' to 'person' so this isn't so obviously an application created to rate women...

Comment: but I want to display only one person per site loop. and it must be order by rate asc @rawb

Comment: hmmm i have 1300 + persons here but it seems they didnt display all the list. hehe. but i think we're getting there.

Comment: It was my understanding that you just wanted the top rated person displayed per-site, but either way this should point you in the right direction!  Similar to the approach above -- I'd recommend sorting the people by site first (in a multidimensional array indexed by site), then sorting each of those site sub-arrays by rating, and then looping through the whole thing (while there are still people left) and echoing out what you need.  Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Using your code I would do something like this:

```
foreach ($site as $item) {
            $maxRate = 0;
            $savePerson = array();
            foreach ($data as $person)
            {
                if($item['acronym'] == $girls['site'] && $person['site'] == $girls['site'] && $person['rate'] > $maxRate)
                {
                    $maxRate = $person['rate'];
                    $savePerson = $person;
                }
            }
           if(!empty($savePerson)){
                    echo 'name: '.$savePerson['site'].'<br>';
                    echo 'site: '.$savePerson['name'].'<br>';
                    echo '<br>';
             }
    }
```

I don't know exactly if you need this condition *$person['site'] == $girls['site']* ..if not you can delete it. That was just my feeling.

btw: you didn't show the $girls array so I just assume is just computed previously. And $data I assume is the $persons array that you are talking about.

Comment: sorry the girls is the persons array. i edited my question above to be sure and clear. :)